# Problems in Installing Pligg on localhost

Tags: mysql, pligg

I'm facing problem in installing Pligg on localhost(xampp). It seem to install successfully but does not login, as the page freezes. If anyone is familiar with this problem, please suggest me how to fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this problem is very very common. I similarly have this issue, even to this day. I've tried installation on Windows XP, Vista, and 7, all have failed.

The only way I'm able to work on Pligg is installing directly onto my hosting server. There I don't get any problems, go through the install process and access my site. Check out [this quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=pligg+localhost+problem) as many of the top links from forums.pligg.com may offer a solution.

Unfortunately though, I haven't found one. To this day I still deploy my Pligg launches onto the server in a sandbox before going live.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/) (Windows) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (Mac) for testing Pligg locally. I know for certain that both are working fine with the current version of Pligg CMS. I believe that I had some issues when I tried XAMPP years ago, so it may have some default setting that Pligg just doesn't agree with.